# Count and Display Combined Select Option Values

Tags: javascript

How would you check the combined sum of select option values and display them in another input using javascript?

```
<form>
    <select id="first">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="second">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input value="combined sum of select value for id='first', id='second'" type="number">
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems have you found?  (Or, is this a request to write code for you?)

Comment: @BobBrown, forgive me, certainly not my intent to have someone write the code for me. I am very new to javascript, well coding all together. I was hoping for some direction on where to start.

Comment: OK.  Try typing "javascript get value of select" into Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google is a good idea to find what you're looking for.

**Look for a Javascript basics and a jQuery tutorial.**
I can recommend [Codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/), they are having very good free online courses for these topics. (Sign-up required but there are many free courses.) The courses are fun to do. They are structured in short video screencasts and afterwards you have to use that knowledge to pass the exercise.
And if you're stuck at some point there are always good hints to solve the exam.

What you are looking for will be something like the script below.

To select the option you can use `$('#first').val()` and to track changes you will use event handlers for the change event `$('#first').on('change', function(){ ... }`.

```js
var adder = (function($){
    var first = 0;
    var second = 0;
    
    var init = function() {
        first = getOption('#first');
        second = getOption('#second');
        var result = add(first,second);
        //console.log(result); // for debugging in console of browser
        update(result);
        //console.log(first,second);
    };
    
    var getOption = function(selector) {
        return parseInt($(selector).val());
    };
    
    var add = function(a,b) {
        return a+b;
    };
    
    var update = function(value) {
        $("#result").val(value);
    };
    
    // event handlers
    $('#first').on('change', function(){
        first = getOption('#first');
        update(add(first,second));
    });
    $('#second').on('change', function(){
        second = getOption('#second');
        update(add(first,second));    
    });
                    
    return {init:init};
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
    adder.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="first">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="second">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input id="result" value="combined sum of select value for id='first', id='second'" type="number"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will add HTML elements together using JavaScript.

```
<input type="number" id="first" value="1"></input>
    <input type="number" id="second" value="2"></input>
    <button onclick="counter()">add</button>
    <p id="display"></p>
<script>
function counter() {
        var first = Number(document.getElementById("first").value);
        var second = Number(document.getElementById("second").value);
        var x = first + second;
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
```